# Calculating the residue of a complex funciton with ln(z) at z=0

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How can I calculate this residue: $$Res\left(\frac {z\ln(z)}{(z^2 +1)^3} , 0\right)  $$ if it's possible at all. 
I know $0$ is a branch point for $\ln(z)$ and therefore isn't a pole, but when i plug this into *Wolfram Mathematica* i do get a value (it's $0$), and that's what confuses me.

Comment: No pole implies no residue.

Comment: What is your definition of "resudue"?  The one I know requires a function analytic in a punctured neighborhood of the point.  This one is not.

Comment: @RonGordon I know, but the notes i have for this exercise state that this has a solution, and that's the actual problem. Perhaps I should try and find a different way of solving the entire exercise. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: What's the entire exercise? Are you trying to compute some integral?

Answer (score 1):

The alleged "function"
$$f(z):={z\>\log z\over (1+z^2)^2}$$
is not defined as a bona fide function in a full punctured neighborhood $\dot U$ of $z=0$, whatever "branch" of $\log$ you might choose. Therefore the residue of this "function" at $0$ is **undefined**.